# Why does SOLR DataImportHandler show more documents added/updated than are in the core?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Using Solr 8.3 with DataImportHandler and the Solr Admin UI and doing a full index of my "project" entity with multiple sub-entities.

Why does the Dataimport page's raw status-output show a larger number of Total Documents Processed than are in the core? Is it reprocessing documents to add child entity data?

After succesfully indexing projects, the number of documents in the core is the same as the number of projects in the database, as expected.

Comment: Core has 5535 documents as expected. Dataimport status says:

Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 32627 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 19m)
Requests: 130,509 114/s, Fetched: 114,090 100/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 32,627 29/s
Started: about 4 hours ago

Comment: If you have duplicate ids (because of a join returning multiple identical rows for example, or because of your ids not being unique) later documents will overwrite the earlier ones.